# I have a shiny mood / My mood is shiny OR I feel shiny

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, idioms

which of the following expressions is better English / sounds better? Which one would you prefer?

- I have a shiny mood / My mood is shiny
- I feel shiny
- I feel shining

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: I think most native speakers wouldn't have much idea what you meant by ***shiny***, however you phrased it. I just looked it up in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shiny) (I doubt any "real" dictionaries are likely to have the definition you're assuming), and I'm guessing a reasonable "mainstream" alternative might be [***bright and breezy***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bright+and+breezy). In which case you'd normally just say *I feel bright and breezy*. Forget about trying to incorporate the word ***mood***.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so would you say that "I feel shining" is better? Or is the meaning still not obvious?

Comment: I don't know where you picked this use of *shiny/shining* up from, or exactly what *you* think it means, but it's not mainstream English. I can't advise on what's best from a *syntactic* perspective for a usage that just sounds weird to me however it's phrased.

Comment: I thought it was a synonym for feeling great / marvellous / fine. However, is the meaning more obvious to a native speaker when using the term "feel breezy"?

Comment: Idiomatically, it's *bright **and** breezy*. Which isn't as popular now as it was a century ago, but [as this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bright+and+breezy&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbright%20and%20breezy%3B%2Cc0), is experiencing something of a comeback in recent decades. Or just stick to "plain" English and actually *say* you feel *great, fine, good*.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. So, is "I am feeling _brilliant_" more "plain" English? Or is it misused in that context?

Comment: If you don't have the luxury of being able to talk much with native speakers and get used to what *they* say, you could use Google to compare [I am feeling brilliant](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ERi2VsO-LpDW8Aeqk4nACQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I+am+feeling+brilliant%22) (2,260 hits) and [I am feeling great](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ahe2VqWqH5DW8Aeqk4nACQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I+am+feeling+great%22) (157,000 hits). But none of this will teach you much about how English *works* - these are issues of established idiomatic preference, not really to do with "right/wrong".

Comment: Just say "I'm in a brilliant mood today" OR "I feel in [tip-top shape](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tip-top)" Brilliant is synonymous with "shiny" , but shiny is usually reserved for objects that have been washed or polished and which reflect light. A "shiny ring", or "shiny hair" for example.

Comment: I'm sorry to say it, but I have the feeling the formulation is a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **shine** is to be **bright** or **noticable** (stand out) or **alert**

> **Rise and shine!**
>   **shining bright**

and is a very **positive attribute** to have

The sentence you may be looking for is

> **I'm feeling shiny**

meaning **I'm feeling bright** *(alive)* or **I'm feeling bright and happy**

> [**I like to feel shiny**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPmqTjMPtbY)

Your friends when they see you may say

> **Look at you shine!**

> You are **shining**
>   This is your **shining** moment

can be used to describe the times when things are **going very well** for someone.

This should not be confused with *(a)* **shiner** which is a **black eye**

It should also not be confused with **glowing**

> **Look at you glow**
>   **You are glowing!**
>   **You've got the glow**

can all be said to a woman who is **pregnant** and who's complexion appears to **brighten up** due to **hormonal transformations** during gestation

Comment: Well, that's good...  but a shiny mood I have never heard of...The only way I would ever say I was feeling shiny is if I had just had a gallon of oil poured over my head, and that circumstance would have more to do with my appearance than my mood!  ;-)

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. I had a wrong perception of the meaning of the word.